# How to printout basic array like a tree in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the basic array:

```
(
  [id] => 1
  [position_level] => 1
  [chief_id] => 9
  [full_name] => Verda Lubowitz
  [employment_start] => 1997-12-01
  [salary] => 1405
)

(
  [id] => 1
  [position_level] => 2
  [chief_id] => 9
  [full_name] => Verda Lubowitz
  [employment_start] => 1997-12-01
  [salary] => 1405
)
```

And I want to printout this array in structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Position level 1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Position level 2</li>
        <li>Position level 2</li>
        <li>Position level 2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Position level 3</li>
            <li>Position level 3</li>
            <li>Position level 3</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Position level 4</li>
                <li>Position level 4</li>
                <li>Position level 4</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Like you сcan see, the structure is like a tree and it related with level of employee position. 
I've spent three days and couldn't to come up with elegant solution, just solution with ugly if and elseif statement, witch will very hard to maintain.
I'm using a laravel and blade templating engine.

Comment: best would be to restructure this array first to a hierachical structure.

Comment: You have to create first child parent relationship and then call recursive function to show tree structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To offer something that I feel like the others are missing, take advantage of the Laravel collections wrapper. There are great methods that can help you not have to do things from scratch.

```
$values = collect($data);

// find highest iteration
$highestLevel = $values->pluck('position_level')->max();

// bunch into groups
$groups = $values->groupBy('position_level');
```

Then, iterate over it in blade:

```
@foreach($groups as $group)

    // start your group position level up tag

    @foreach($group as $value)

        // do stuff here with $value being your individual sub array 
        // that you can access via object syntax ($value->position_level)

    @endforeach

    // end your group ul tag

@endforeach
```

Lastly, I would point out that HTML doesn't actually have a visual tree structure to it. That is how we code it so it's easier to understand, and that is also what the browser dev tools show us.

So if you're wanting an appropriately indented version, you can replicate the blade code in your controller and build a string. For each 'group', or level, you would prepend the line with the level number times the tab length (maybe 4 spaces).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to reorder your array based on the `position_level`. You can do it by simply looping through the array, and construct a new one where the index is the `position_level` and the content is all of the rows in that position. Then you can use a recursive function to achieve what you want.

The code (with sample data):

```
<?php

$testarray = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'position_level' => 1,
        'chief_id' => 9,
        'full_name' => 'Verda Lubowitz 1',
        'employment_start' => '1997-12-01',
        'salary' => 1405,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'position_level' => 3,
        'chief_id' => 9,
        'full_name' => 'Verda Lubowitz 3',
        'employment_start' => '1997-12-01',
        'salary' => 1405,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'position_level' => 2,
        'chief_id' => 9,
        'full_name' => 'Verda Lubowitz 2',
        'employment_start' => '1997-12-01',
        'salary' => 1405,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'position_level' => 2,
        'chief_id' => 9,
        'full_name' => 'Verda Lubowitz 2',
        'employment_start' => '1997-12-01',
        'salary' => 1405,
    ],
];

// Initialize an empty array
$newarray = [];
// Loop through original array
foreach($testarray as $entry) {
    // Append entry to $newarray[position_level]
    $newarray[$entry['position_level']][] = $entry;
}

// Call the recursive function starting from level 1
draw_tree($newarray, 1);

function draw_tree($array, $startlevel) {
    // No more levels, return
    if(!isset($array[$startlevel])) {
        return;
    }
    // Draw the current level
    echo '<ul>';
    // And its contents
    foreach($array[$startlevel] as $entry) {
        echo '<li>' . $entry['full_name'] . '</li>';
    }
    // Call the next level before closing the ul tag
    draw_tree($array, $startlevel + 1);
    // Close the ul tag
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

The output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Verda Lubowitz 1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Verda Lubowitz 2</li>
        <li>Verda Lubowitz 2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Verda Lubowitz 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I set up a working example here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da9784e8526de18f9fe34dcf859ac3feee44ad63

Note that this function can't "skip" levels, so if you have a level 1 and level 3 entry, the function will only draw the level 1 and then returns. If this is the case, you need a bit more sophisticated solution, but I assume you don't have missing (empty) levels.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array of data.
Group the array of data by Position level like below

```
[
 "position_level_1" => [
    (
     [id] => 1
     [position_level] => 1
     [chief_id] => 9
     [full_name] => Verda Lubowitz
     [employment_start] => 1997-12-01
     [salary] => 1405
    ),
    ...
    ...
  ],
  "position_level_2" => [
(
  [id] => 1
  [position_level] => 2
  [chief_id] => 9
  [full_name] => Verda Lubowitz
  [employment_start] => 1997-12-01
  [salary] => 1405
)
  ]
]
```

After formatting all those data loop through it. use unorder list to draw those data in html.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach loop`:

```
<ul>
   @foreach($array_1 as $data)
 <li>{{$data->title_1}}</li>
   @endforeach
<ul>
  @foreach($array_2 as $data)
    <li>{{$data->title_2}}</li>
  @endforeach
    <ul>
      @foreach($array_3 as $data)
        <li>{{$data->title_3}}</li>
      @endforeach
        <ul>
         @foreach($array_4 as $data)
            <li>{{$data->title_4}}</li>
         @endforeach
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: And how do you get `$array_1`? Why is there no relation between the different arrays?